# Joomla to Wordpress migration from HTML files

Tags: joomla, wordpress, data-migration

I know there exists tools that migrates Joomla to Wordpress at database level. But my problem is I don't have access to Joomla database anymore. I only have whole Joomla! 1.0.x site's local copy which was taken 2 years ago. Is it possible to migrate that posts to my Wordpress site?

Or should I copy-paste all content to a CSV file and use an Excel importer ?

Comment: Interesting would love to hear solution..!!

Comment: There are no tools to migrate Joomla articles to Wordpress for Joomla 1.0. There are commercial extensions but these are for Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically for Joomla , but I have made such a thing in the past several times while migrating from some Custom Cms's

It will depend on HOW BIG is your site and how much information you need to migrate (and it's complexity) but you can always go for HTML `SCRAPPING` / `PARSING`. 
As from this point , GIYBF . And your Coding skills.

One of the best one IMHO is [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) ,and another that many recommend but I personally never used are [htmlSQL](https://github.com/hxseven/htmlSQL)  And [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) .

But there are also a lot of Tutorials on [google](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=HTML%20scrapping%20PHP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) ( [here also](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=HTML%20scrapping%20PHP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=sfm&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=HTML%20scrapping%20PHP%20tutorials&oq=HTML%20scrapping%20PHP%20tutorials&gs_l=serp.3...69582.72699.0.72855.10.10.0.0.0.0.226.1246.0j5j2.7.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.lw-D9aQl-04&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dGI&fp=51e9216bba78bad&biw=1680&bih=857) and [EXAMPLE TUT](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/)) explaining how to do it , and also a lot of [questions here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simple%20HTML%20DOm%20) and a [list of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping) (not PHP exclusive).
The other option (which is basically the same , but without libraries) , is going or REGEX , like in this very [simple example](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial)..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the DB, then you don't have the content. All of the content on a Joomla site is stored in the DB. If you only have the Joomla files, there is nothing to copy and paste in to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script. http://azeemkhan.info/2008/joomla2wordpress-import-wizard-v3/ Note you will need to install an old version of wordpress first and THEN upgrade your wordpress version.

There's a useful guide on this [here](http://www.iamboredsoiblog.eu/2009/04/joomla-migration-to-wordpress.html#more) and info on utf-8 support [here](http://www.iamboredsoiblog.eu/2009/04/joomla2wordpress-import-wizard-with-utf.html#more).

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have Joomla database.

Comment: You do. Because without a database Joomla has no posts nor articles nor module content